# How to use ng-repeat on this data format?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to use `ng-repeat` in below format of data:

**Controller:**

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('https://blablabla').success(function(data) {
    $scope.PartnerResultsBO = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
   $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);
```

Data:

```
{
  "PartnerResultsBO": {
    "resultCount": 36,
    "listings": [
      {
        "id": 643762817,
        "makeName": "Honda",
        "modelName": "Accord"
      },
      {
        "id": 642121018,
        "makeName": "Honda",
        "modelName": "Accord"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="phones">
          <li ng-repeat="listing in listings.listings | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
                <p>{{listing.makeName}}</p>
                <p>{{listing.modelName}}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: `listings.listings`? not `PartnerResultsBO.PartnerResultsBO.listings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `listings.listings` to `PartnerResultsBO.PartnerResultsBO.listings`

Or fetch the listing from your data and assign it to scope variable listings

```
  $scope.listings = data.PartnerResultsBO.listings;
```

and keep your html as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Only your variable name is incorrect.Add one variable in controller listings or change in template from listings.listings to PartnerResultsBO.PartnerResultsBO.listings as @Joy suggested.Both are correct.I guess you just did typo.Your concept is clear.

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('https://blablabla').success(function(data) {
    $scope.PartnerResultsBO = data.PartnerResultsBO;
    $scope.listings= $scope.PartnerResultsBO;
    console.log(data);
  });
   $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);
```